# О тексте и подтексте

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми туза." это текст без подтекста,
- указание "Возьми только туза." это текст с подтекстом?

Answer (score 2):

Подтекст означает, что во фразе есть что-то помимо прямого смысла. Это что-то может быть отсылкой к цитате, к принятыми в данной среде разговорам, обычаям, моделям поведения. Суть подтекста как раз в том, что выявляется он не из текста, а из контекста.

В вашем описании никаких скрытых смыслов в обеих фразах не видно. Однако, если допустить, что эту фразу произнося представители криминального мира, играющие в "пьяницу", где шестерка берет только туза, то ваши рассуждения могут быть истиной. Возможны обстоятельства, когда с подтекстом будут обе фразы.

**Примеры**

Борис Гребенщиков в 2008 написал песню со следующими словами:

> Анютины глазки и божьи коровки
> Нас не узнают – мы придём в обновке,
> В новых одеждах, с новыми глазами,
> Они спросят: «Кто мы» - «Догадайтесь сами».
>
> Только мы вышли – как уже вернёмся,
> Они удивятся – а мы засмеёмся,
> Как тут не плакать, как не смеяться,
> Они переварят – и присоединятся.
>
> На дворе поленья, а на них кошка,
> Хватит лить слёзы – посмотри в окошко.
> Какое там небо, какие в нём краски,
> Божьи коровки, да анютины глазки.

Если не знать, что БГ в это время увлекался буддизмом, можно решить, что эта песня описывает лишь летний деревенский пейзаж. Однако, если об этом факте знать, то становиться ясно, что тут описывается смерть и последующая реинкарнация.

Другим примером может служить известное стихотворение Цветаевой "Мне нравится, что вы больны не мной...".

Не зная контекста, можно решить, что в стихотворении заложен скрытый смысл и слова надо воспринимать не буквально, а иносказательно, и на самом деле лирическая героиня как раз "больна" человеком, которому обращено стихотворение. Но если знать, что эти стихи посвящены новоиспечённому мужу сестры поэтессы, а сама Марина Цветаева в этот момент была счастлива замужем за Сергеем Эфроном, становится понятным, что смысл тут прямой, и лирическая героиня счастлива как раз тем, что больны не ей, а она не им.

Comment: 1. Спасибо за помощь.

2. Пожалуйста, приведите два простых примера выявления подтекста из контекста.

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.

Answer (score 0):

СИТУАЦИЯ 1

Вы - фокусник-иллюзионист, карты лежат на столике, и вы говорите участнику:
 - (1)Возьмите туза/ (2)возьмите только туза.

В этой ситуации фраза 1 воспринимается как нормальная, а фраза 2 - как коммуникативно неверная, несущая лишнюю информацию. Человек чувствует это и начинает нервничать.

СИТУАЦИЯ 2 (ДИАЛОГИ)

- Я могу взять еще одну карту.
- Возьми туза  (1)
- Я хочу взять туза и короля.
- Возьми только туза (2)

В приведенных диалогах фразы 1 и 2 употреблены верно. Таким образом, эти выражения - только материал, из которого строится текст, и рассматривать их вне текста, отнесенного к определенной ситуации, вообще не имеет смысла. Коммуникативность текста в данном случае можно определить как  характеристику, определяющую необходимость и достаточность сообщаемой информации.

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения, включая гипотезу о моей профессии.